# Java collection list memory structure

Tags: java, arrays

When we write -

`ArrayList al=new ArrayList(10);`

Sometimes write an array like -
`RefVar = new dataType[10];`

What is happening in memory? whether the memory is located in continuous  order or scattered order?

Answer (score 3):

In principle, the Java language - neither the language spec nor the VM spec - doesn't mention how objects and arrays are to be implemented and does not guarantee consecutive memory allocation.

In practice, though, arrays are consecutive (only in their first dimension!), and `ArrayList` is implemented using an array, therefore the item references inside it are consecutive. Although the implementation of `ArrayList` includes other fields which are separate from the actual array.

If you add an element to an `ArrayList` whose internal array is already full, it will internally allocate a new, bigger array and copy all the existing element references to it. So even when that happens, the element references will still be consecutive (in practice).

Comment: Maybe mention something about growing the AL beyond the initiallly allocated size?

Answer (score 0):

For `array`s the elements will be in a continuous memory location.

And since `ArrayList` maintains index based system for its elements as it uses array data structure then its element also remain in a continuous memory location.